# In THREE.js, how can I make textures resolution-independent and render without blurriness?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to apply textures to meshes in THREE.js, but to get an acceptable level of clarity, I am forced to use PNGs much larger than desirable, up to several hundred pixels squared in size.  If I were to use something simple such as an eight-by-eight checkered pattern, for example, the smallest resolution possible looks like a bunch of dots.

The code being used for the textures is `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("sprites/land1.png");`

Comment: Maybe you can share a screenshot?

Comment: Of course!  [Here](http://i.imgur.com/zOh4YOx.png) is what I get when I use a small .png file.  The exact one used in the screenshot is [this](http://i.imgur.com/230gSTp.png).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in [this example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_minecraft.html) you need to set the filtering of the texture.

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'texture.png' );
texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;
```