# Three js, block textures are blured

Tags: javascript, web, three.js

I'm trying to make a 3D block with the [three.js](http://threejs.org/) library.
I've done it. Now i wan't to put a texture on it. I did that and it's working :

```
var textureHerbe = [
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/border.gif')}),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/border.gif')}),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/top.gif')}),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/bottom.gif')}),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/border.gif')}),
     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/border.gif')})
];
```

Thats the result :
[image]
But look at this, it's blured !
So i looked at this [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371299/in-three-js-how-can-i-make-textures-resolution-independent-and-render-without-b). And i don't know how to mix my code with his solution's code :/
Do you jnow how i can do it ? Thx and have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are loading the same texture several times. So assign it to a variable and then make the textures resolution-independent and render without blurriness.

```
var border_tex = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/border.gif');
border_tex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
border_tex.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

var top_tex = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/top.gif');
top_tex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
top_tex.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

var bottom_tex = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/texture/herbe/bottom.gif');
bottom_tex.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
bottom_tex.minFilter = THREE.LinearMipMapLinearFilter;

var textureHerbe = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: border_tex } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: border_tex } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: top_tex } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: bottom_tex } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: border_tex } ),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: border_tex } ),
];
```