# Three Js - How to fix the blurry images on the vertices of an icosahedron

Tags: three.js

I was trying to make a rotating icosahedorn with images on each vertex using three js, but the images look blurred. Can anyone please help me? js fiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/b2tncLh8/

```
<div id="container"></div>

var $container = $('#container');
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
});
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, 1, 0.1, 10000);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var Ico;

scene.add(camera);
renderer.setSize(576, 576);

// Making the canvas responsive
function onWindowResize() {

  var screenWidth = $(window).width();
  if (screenWidth <= 479) {
    renderer.setSize(300, 300);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 767) {
    renderer.setSize(400, 400);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 991) {
    renderer.setSize(500, 500);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 1200) {
    renderer.setSize(450, 450);
  } else if (screenWidth <= 1366) {
    renderer.setSize(550, 550);
  }
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}
onWindowResize();
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);


$container.append(renderer.domElement);

// Camera
camera.position.z = 200;

// Material
var greyMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: new THREE.Color("rgb(125,127,129)"),
  emissive: new THREE.Color("rgb(125,127,129)"),
  specular: new THREE.Color("rgb(125,127,129)"),
  shininess: "100000000",
  shading: THREE.FlatShading,
  transparent: 1,
  opacity: 1
});

var L2 = new THREE.PointLight();
L2.position.z = 1900;
L2.position.y = 1850;
L2.position.x = 1000;
scene.add(L2);
camera.add(L2);

var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(125, 1), greyMat);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
scene.add(Ico);
var trackballControl = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
trackballControl.rotateSpeed = 1.0; 
trackballControl.noZoom = true;

// sprites
var txtLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
txtLoader.setCrossOrigin("");
var textures = [
    "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg",
  "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/colors.png",
  "https://threejs.org/examples/textures/metal.jpg"
];
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();
console.log(Ico.geometry.vertices.length);
Ico.geometry.vertices.forEach(function(vertex, index){
    var texture = txtLoader.load(textures[index % 3]);
    var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: texture});
    var sprite = new THREE.Sprite(spriteMaterial);
  sprite.scale.setScalar(10);
  direction.copy(vertex).normalize();
  sprite.position.copy(vertex).addScaledVector(direction, 10);
  Ico.add(sprite);
});

function update() {
  Ico.rotation.x += 2 / 500;
  Ico.rotation.y += 2 / 500;
}

// Render
function render() {
  trackballControl.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  update();
}
render();
```

Comment: Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14414140/4045502) and play around with filtering of a texture.

Answer (score 1):

so i'm guessing because you scale the textures a lot, you're wondering how to get it more blocky and less blurry? If that's the case, with each loaded texture you should set `texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter`.

`magFilter` specifies the behavior when a portion of a texture occupies more pixels than the texture's native resolution.

`NearestFilter` basically returns colors for the UV coordinates for pixel at Math.floor(UV.x*width). So if you have a resolution of 64 pixels, it'll color in 64 blocks across and 64 down. Nice and pixelated.

With the default, linearfilter - it will lerp in between pixel perfect values, giving you the blurring effect. [The documentation for THREE.Texture can give you more info on things to try if you get stuck.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture)

[See in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/OtterFamily/b2tncLh8/4/)